# CEC client Hybrid help

Tags: cec-client

I hope someone can help me.  I've got a [pulse-eight cec adapter](https://www.pulse-eight.com/p/104/usb-hdmi-cec-adapter)and my TV is my main monitor for PC.
I made 5 simple stand-alone scripts linked to F8 and up to F12 on the keyboard. 
They turn tv on-off and HDMI switch, but I would like to expand my idea a little.
So I Made a Script that turns the TV Off (using cec command) when pc screen goes off but there is a problem with that. 
If I switch sources to watch TV that script will trigger and turn off in the middle of me watching a film.

I want to modify [this guys](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/02/control-your-raspberry-pi-with-your-tv-remote/) script to do all the work but my grep foo isn't good enough :-(

I added < function filter_key2(){ grep "0f:80:30:00:30:00" <( echo "$3" ) >
and the line below in the hopes to be able to only run < echo standby 0 | /usr/bin/cec-client -s > with is the line to turn tv off only when only when this line is triggered < if  filter_key3 "$l"; then echo "source switched back" fi >

My tv does not report the active source but it does Broadcast routing change info if cec-client is running,

So how do make it work?

Next question is if this works cec-client script will be running in the background. 
How do I echo control stuff to cec-client from within the script?
I can only have one instance of cec-client running how ever it can stay running always.
I discovered that when it is running from terminal I can type "echo on 0 " whilst its displaying debug info and tv will turn on.
This script below will need to take over the list I mentioned earlier with the F keys.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Simple script to control your Raspberry Pi with your TV remote using libcec
#
# Copyleft 2017 by Ignacio Nunez Hernanz <nacho _a_t_ ownyourbits _d_o_t_ com>
# GPL licensed (see the end of file) * Use at your own risk!
#
# You can set this to be run in your desktop "startup programs", or 
# at the last line of /etc/rc.local, just to say a couple options
#
# keys:
#   OK   - launch kodi 
#   up   - launch browser
#   down - change wallpaper (this is a custom script of mine)
#   left - suspend my desktop computer
#   back - exit desktop session
#
# You can hit 'stop' to enter "mouse mode", or 'play' to exit it.
# In "mouse mode" you can move around the mouse with the remote arrows, hit ok
# to double-click.
#
# This is just an example to provide ideas, so you should change what each button does.
#

USER=user                        # user that will be logged in
OSDCOLOR=red                   # color for xosd messages
MOUSESPEED=50                  # how many pixels a mouse will move on each press
#dbg=echo                      # uncomment to just print the command without executing it
VERBOSE=0                      # print echov lines
#DRY_RUN="yes"                 # uncomment to actually ignore button presses

type cec-client &>/dev/null || { echo "cec-client is requiered"; exit; }
type xdotool    &>/dev/null || NOXDOTOOL=#
trap "exit 1" INT 
#USR_CMD="su - $USER -c"
#_XAUTH="/home/$USER/.Xauthority"

function          d(){ eval "$NOXDOTOOL $@"                                            ; }
function      echov(){ [[ "$VERBOSE" == "1" ]] && echo $@                              ; }
function filter_key(){ grep -q "key pressed: $1 .* duration" <( echo "$2" )            ; }
function mouse_move(){ XAUTHORITY="$_XAUTH" DISPLAY=:0 xdotool mousemove_relative -- $@; }
function mouseclick(){ XAUTHORITY="$_XAUTH" DISPLAY=:0 xdotool click --repeat 2 1      ; }
function    osdecho(){ type osd_cat &>/dev/null && echo "$@" | XAUTHORITY="$_XAUTH" DISPLAY=:0 osd_cat -ptop -Acenter -c$OSDCOLOR; }
function          filter_key2(){ grep "0f:80:30:00:30:00" <( echo "$3" )            ; }
function          filter_key3(){ grep "0f:80:10:00:10:00" <( echo "$4" )            ; }

while :; do 
   | while read l; do
    echov $l

    [[ "$DRY_RUN" != "" ]] && continue

#     pgrep kodi && { echov "Ignoring key, because Kodi is running"; continue; }
    if  filter_key2 "$l"; then
      echo "source switched away"
    fi  
    if  filter_key3 "$l"; then
      echo "source switched back"
    fi   
    if  filter_key "select" "$l"; then
      [[ "$MOUSEMODE" == "1" ]] && mouseclick || {
        $dbg echo "ok key press"
        }

    fi
    if  filter_key "up" "$l"; then
      [[ "$MOUSEMODE" == "1" ]] && mouse_move 0 -$MOUSESPEED || \
      $dbg echo "up key press"
    fi  
    if  filter_key "left" "$l"; then
      [[ "$MOUSEMODE" == "1" ]] && mouse_move -$MOUSESPEED 0 || \
        $dbg echo "left key press"
    fi  
    if  filter_key "down" "$l"; then
      [[ "$MOUSEMODE" == "1" ]] && mouse_move 0 $MOUSESPEED || \
        $dbg echo "down key press" 
    fi  
    if  filter_key "right" "$l"; then
      [[ "$MOUSEMODE" == "1" ]] && mouse_move $MOUSESPEED 0 || \
        $dbg echo "right key press"
    fi  
    if  filter_key "exit" "$l"; then
        { echo "exiting"
        killall cec-client 
        killall cec-test.sh
        }
    fi  
    if  filter_key "stop" "$l"; then
        echo "mouse mode on"
        MOUSEMODE=1
    fi
    if  filter_key "play" "$l"; then
        echo "mouse mode off"
        MOUSEMODE=0
    fi
  done
done
trap - INT
exit 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Please let me know if I should post my code I'm referring to to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Please write proper sentences with some more punctuation. It's hard to read and I stopped after some lines.

Comment: Sorry about the sentences. I hope it a bit clearer now.